# How to convert a RDD<String> to a RDD<Vector> in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a file where each line is in this way

```
info1,info2
info3,info4
...
```

After scanning it, I want to run the k-means algorithm:

```
  val rawData = sc.textFile(myFile)
  val converted = convertToVector(rawData)
  val kmeans = new KMeans()
  kmeans.setK(10)
  kmeans.setRuns(10)
  kmeans.setEpsilon(1.0e-6)
  val model = kmeans.run(rawData) -> problem: k-means accepts only RDD<Vector>
```

Because k-means only accepts `RDD<Vector>`, I created a function that converts my `RDD<String>` `rawData` to a `RDD<Vector>`. But I'm getting stuck on how to do this, this function below is work in progress:

```
def converToVector(rawData: RDD[String]): RDD[Vector] = {

    //TODO...
    val toConvert = rawData.collect().toVector
    val map = rawData.map {
      line => line.split(",").toVector
    }

    map
  }
```

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very basic operation considering that each line of your input file is a hypothetical vector represented by a comma separated string.

You just need to map each string entrie, split it on the separator and then create a dense Vector from it:

```
val parsedData = rawData.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(',').map(_.toDouble)))
```

Comment: thanks, so if i want to convert to RDD<Vector> i always have to use `Vectors.dense`?

Comment: well unless your vector is actually sparse and you have as an input file a sparse vector representation, you'll have to use dense.

Comment: how works exactly this `map(_.toDouble)` ? IMHO, convert the string into doubles?

Comment: well considering info[1-n] as numerical values, you can convert your values directly into double. But it doesn't seem to be the case here, is it?

Comment: these info are doubles

Comment: then the code i gave you should be working fine! the `map` isn't specific just for RDDs. In Scala, you can map over Collections, considering it's a hybrid functional and object-oriented language.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83408/discussion-between-eliasah-and-oirc).